# Send POST HttpWebRequest and don't need to receive response

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webclient, httpwebresponse

I send a POST request by this way:

```
HttpWebResponse res = null;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] loginDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(requestCommand);
req.ContentLength = loginDataBytes.Length;
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(loginDataBytes, 0, loginDataBytes.Length);
stream.Close();
//line below is my way to send request, but it return a response.
res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

I just want to send request to WebServer and I don't want to receive reponse. It wastes time and bandwidth. Are there anyway to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: comment the line res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

Comment: you can always create a queue (for example in a file to be faster) and pool that file for changes every once-and-a-while and process it in other thread...

Comment: @dankyy1 without that line, the data will never be sent...

Comment: @Tiang: the `HttpWebRequest` class isn't good for your problem. try to find another classes.

Comment: @Tiang: Did you see [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx)?

Comment: @Tiang: I'm trying to find one. but I didn't find one until now. I just saw [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way. The HTTP protocol is two way. It is a request/response protocol. You need to call the `GetResponse` method if you want to send the request that you prepared earlier.

Comment: Are there anyway to limit reponse package size or limit reponse content lenght ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Yes, you could modify the server side script to return less data if some request parameter is sent.

Comment: Isn't there any way to make an asynchronous request and simply don't read the response stream?

Comment: @Delta: I'm a newbie of webclient, Could you give me a code sample about asynchronous request? Thank you very much